# OpenCV CameraBridgeViewBase gives 14 FPS at best. Why?

Tags: android, opencv, camera, frame-rate

Using `JavaCameraView` in OpenCV, I only get 14 frame per second. No calculation is done. Neither image processing, nor feature detection. Only receiving the camera frame intact. But FPS doesn't go over 14. Why is that?

Is it bad implementation or I'm missing something?

Comment: It's quite well explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676046/why-fps-is-not-same-as-original-camera-app?lq=1